# Output json specified data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I use phppagebuilder for editing my pages html content and in pages table from mysql i have this json generated code when i save:

```
{"html":["[block slug=\"contact\" id=\"IDL8P4JHM1GYPVX0\"]"],"components":[[{"tagName":"phpb-block","content":"","attributes":{"slug":"contact","id":"IDL8P4JHM1GYPVX0"}}]],"css":"* { box-sizing: border-box; } body {margin: 0;}","style":[],"blocks":{"en":{"IDL8P4JHM1GYPVX0":{"settings":{"attributes":{"style-identifier":"IDL8P4QRULUOPXC0"}},"blocks":[],**"html":** <- all page html is here
```

I need to extract the last "html": data after "blocks":[] to retrive all my html code to output in my php homepage.

php homepage output:

```
$s = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT `data` FROM `pages` WHERE `id` = 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($s);
echo $row['data'];
```

but i get all the json code... and i need only my html code from the builder.

phppagebulder source : https://github.com/HansSchouten/PHPagebuilder

Comment: you could try to create a regex expression to identify `¨blocks¨:[]`

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and isn't the best option in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to solve this.
First you can fetch all data and parse it using PHP:

```
$s = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `data` FROM `pages` WHERE `id` = 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($s);

$data = json_decode($row[0], true);

preg_match('/id="([^"]+)"/', $data['html'][0], $m);

$id = $m[1];

echo $data['blocks']['en'][$id]['html'] . PHP_EOL ;
```

Second way is parsing JSON by MySQL:

```
$s = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `data`->\"$.blocks.en.*.html\" FROM `pages` WHERE `id` = 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($s);

var_dump($row[0]);
```

[php code online](https://phpize.online/s/f)

Comment: Thank you for your response,  the thing is the IDL8P4JHM1GYPVX0 is changing on every save when i edit the page...

Comment: @Fido, so first you need to parse id: https://phpize.online/s/x

Comment: @Fido, Please check my updated answer

Comment: Working like a charm, god bless you, thanks!